# Advice on setting up a Qt3D scene with redundant objects

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 3d, qt3d

I'm new to the Qt3D module and am currently writing a game in Qt5/C++ using Qt3D. This question is about "Am I on the correct path?" or "Can you give me some advice on...".

The scene of the game has a static part (the "world") and some objects (buildings and movable units). Some of the buildings might be animated in the future, but most of them are very static (but of course destructible).

I divide the quesion into two parts: How to handle copies of the same model placed at different positions in the scene and how to manage the scene as a whole in the viewer class.

**Redundant objects in the scene:**

Of course the objects share the same library of buildings / movable units, so it would be dumb to upload the models for these objects to the graphics card for every instance of such a unit. I read through the documentation of QGLSceneNode, from which I guess that it is designed to share the same QGeometryData among multiple scene nodes, but apply different transformations in order to place the objects at different positions in my scene. Sharing the same QGLSceneNode for all instances of a building would be the wrong way, I guess.

I currently have a unit "library class" telling me the properties of each type of building / movable unit, among other things the geometry including textures. Now, I'd provide a QGeometryData for each building in this library class, which is uploaded on the loading procedure of the game (if I decide to do this for *all* buildings at startup...).

When creating a new instance of a unit, I'd now create a new QGLSceneNode, request the QGeometryData (which is explicitly shared) from the library and set it on the node. Then I set the transformation for this new node and put it in my scene. This leads us to the second part of my question:

**Manage the scene as a whole:**

My "scene" currently is neither a QGLSceneNode nor a QGLAbstractScene, but a struct of some QGLSceneNodes, one for each object (or collection of objects) in the scene. I see three approaches:

- My current approach, but I guess it's "the wrong way".
- The composition: Putting everything as child nodes in one root QGLSceneNode. This seemed the correct way for me, until I realized that it is very difficult to access specific nodes in such a composition. But when would I even need to access such "specific" nodes? Most operations require to take all nodes into account (rendering them, updating positions for animations), or even operate on a signal-slot-basis so I even don't need to find the nodes manually at all. For example, animations can be done using QPropertyAnimations. Acting on events can also be done by connecting a QObject in the game engine core (all buildings are QObjects in the engine's core part) with the corresponding QGLSceneNode.

  But this approach has another downside: During rendering, I might need to change some properties of the QGLPainter. I'm not sure which properties I need to change, this is because I don't know Qt3D enough and can't guess what can be done without changing the properties (for example: using a specific shader to render a specific scene node).
- Then I found QGLAbstractScene, but I can't see the advantages when comparing with the two solutions above, since I can't define the rendering process in the scene. But maybe it's not the correct location where to define it?

**Which is the best approach to manage such a scene in Qt3D?**

With "best" I mean: What am I going to do wrong? What can I do better? What other things should I take into account? Have I overlooked anything important in the Qt3D library?